# Is my better score with a different machine learning model statistically significant?

Tags: machine-learning, p-value, feature-selection

I have a question concerning the p-value and how you can say that *this* selection of features is better than *that* other one.

To make things simple let's assume that I'm working on the spam classification problem.

I've tested two different ways to do my feature engineering :

**OPTION 1** = [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)
Accuracy : 90%

**OPTION 2** = [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)
Accuracy : 91%

Those results seem pretty close with an edge for tf-idf.
However this could be caused by the random seed, the dataset I trained my algorithm on, the dataset I tested my data on etc.

My question is : **can I say that OPTION2 is better than OPTION1 ?**

I looked on Wikipedia for information on `statistical significance` and `null hypothesis` and from what I've understood I need to compute the probabilty of my test happening if *OPTION2 is better than OPTION1* (H0)

How can I do this ?

And there seems to be a lot of controversy around the p-value (how do you set the threshold ? the fact that it is mistaken with the probability of the null hypothesis being true etc) so in the end am I not better off running my algorithm different times with different random seeds and on different parts of the dataset and do some sort of average on those values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not look for a p-value to start with. First, how did you assess the accuracy of your models ?

I will assume you obtained the performance using cross validation. Then, you also have access to the standard deviation of the accuracy (that can be seen as a random value as well). Per example, these two situations are completely different :

**Situation 1 :**

- tf-idf $(90\%, 90\%,91\%,90\%,89\%)$
- Bag of words $(90\%, 92\%,91\%,91\%,91\%)$

**Situation 2 :**

- tf-idf $(80\%, 100\%,95\%,90\%,85\%)$
- Bag of words $(90\%, 92\%,94\%,88\%,91\%)$

I would be more confident that features generated using a Bag of words approach produce a better model than these generated using tf-idf in situation 1 than in situation 2.

Now, if you want to put this in a statistical significance test, you could do the following :

Calling $S_{tf-idf}$ the random value representing the accuracy of the model obtained using a tf-idf preprocessing and $S_{BoW}$ the random value representing the accuracy of the model obtained using a bag of words preprocessing, the hypothesis would be :

$$\mu_{BoW}=\mathbb{E}[S_{BoW}]>\mu_{tf-idf}=\mathbb{E}[S_{tf-idf}]$$

Which turns out to be [sample means comparison](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm).

Comment: I really like your answer, this was what I was leaning towards. Didn't know about sample means comparison but its exactly what I'm looking for, thanks a lot !